# Как переконвертировать PDF файл в HTML?

Tags: html, pdf

Как переконвертировать PDF файл в HTML? Может знаете какие-нибудь веб-сервисы, которые наилучшим образом это делают?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень легко ищется в гугле по ключевым словам. 
[Результат 1](http://document.online-convert.com/ru/convert-to-pdf)
[Результат 2](http://www.zamzar.com/ru/convert/pdf-to-html/)
[Результат 3](http://ru.pdftoword.org/pdf-to-html/)
[Результат 4](http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/)

Если это Вас не устраивает - попробуйте написать свой парсер для этих целей (но это уже совсем <s>другая история</s> другой вопрос...)

Answer (score 1):

Я знаю ответ: **Fine Reader**

Но там это настолько сложно - что выходит за границы разумности и рациональности.